# How to get refresh token using access token in scribe

Tags: oauth, scribe

i have got access token now i want to have refresh token so that i can refresh my access token whenever needed.
i used fallowing code but it returned error response

```
  **OAuthRequest request = new OAuthRequest(Verb.POST, "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token");
    request.addBodyParameter("grant_type", "refresh_token");
    request.addBodyParameter("refresh_token", "accesstoken string"); 

    request.send();**
```

any ideas how to get refresh token??????

Comment: Adding those two lines couldn't cause a problem itself. Just to clarify, in "accesstoken string" you have `accessToken.getToken()`? If yes then check the rest of your code.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that using the following code

```
OAuthRequest request = new OAuthRequest(Verb.POST, "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token");
    request.addBodyParameter("grant_type", "refresh_token");
    request.addBodyParameter("refresh_token", accessToken.getToken()); // were accessToken is the Token object you want to refresh.
    request.addBodyParameter("client_id", your clientID);
    request.addBodyParameter("client_secret", your clientSecret);
    Response response = request.send();
```

Answer (score 0):

A refresh token is obtained in offline scenarios as mentioned in https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#offline
Make sure access_type is 'offline'

Answer (score 0):

Actually Scribe doesn't let you to get a refresh token. I had to customize it to make it posible, I did it because i didn't have choice, even the owner(Jerome Leleu) of that library doesn't give maintenance, he is working in a new version called Pac4j.